# CSS issue with my website when switching from portrait to landscape and then back to portrait again

Tags: html, css, mobile, tailwind-css, responsive

I have a Nuxt.js website with minimal CSS and some Tailwind, and I'm having what seems to be a basic CSS issue. I am trying to make my website responsive and mobile friendly--and it almost works as expected. It loads correctly in portrait mode, and when rotated to landscape, also looks great. But when rotated back to portrait mode one more time, it suddenly show the background color (using red) on half of the menu area at the top.

Also, the menu at the top become more narrow and smaller, and the text in the main area shifts and becomes smaller. There is a canvas element for a javascript animation, and if I remove that, the responsive code does in fact works perfectly. Any ideas on how to fix this code would be greatly appreciated.

The MyHeader.vue component is simply a swath of HTML pulled in to the main program:

```
<template>
    <div
      class="bg-white text-purple-600 w-full"
      :class="{ 'absolute w-full h-screen top-0 left-0': menu }">
      <div class="container ww-full sm:mx-auto flex flex-wrap">

        <div class="w-auto p-3">
        <!-- Can add opitonal text on left side -->
        </div>

        <!-- Desktop nav list -->
        <nav class="hidden sm:block">
          <ul class="flex">
            <li
              v-for="(item, index) in items"
              :key="index">

              <NuxtLink class="hover:bg-gray-300 p-3 block" :to="item.href">{{item.title}}</NuxtLink>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="ml-auto sm:hidden p-3" @click="$event => menu = !menu">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </div>
            
      </div>

      <!-- Mobile nav list -->
      <nav v-show="menu" class="w-full">
        <ul class="flex flex-col text-center">
        <li
          v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">

          <NuxtLink class="hover:bg-gray-300 p-3 block" 
          :to="item.href">{{item.title}}</NuxtLink>
  
        </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    

    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {     
    data() {

      return {
        menu: false,
        
        items: [
          {
            title: 'Linux',
            href: '/networking'
          },
          {
            title: 'WebDev',
            href: '/webdev'
          },
          {
            title: 'Biz',
            href: '/enterprise'
          },
          
          {
            title: 'Coding',
            href: '/coding'
          }

        ]
      }
    }
  }
 </script>
```

Then, MyHeader.vue is embedded into the main web page like this:

```
<div class="bg-black">

<!--<img src="../assets/logo.svg" width="100px" alt="logo" /><br clear="all" />-->

    <MyHeader class="w-full" />
    <canvas class="bg-black" ref="canvas"></canvas>

    <div class="absolute text-white text-center 
    uppercase tracking-wide w-full max-w-2xl
    px-6" style="top: 50%; transform:translate(-50%, -50%); left: 50%;
    width: 100%;" id="container">

    <h1 id="patrickKennedy" class="font-laoX text-sm
      opacity-0" style="transform:translateY(30px)"> Patrick Kennedy</h1>

    <p class="font-exo2 text-4xl opacity-0" id="oneWithAn" style="transform:translateY(30px)">
      Information Technology guru available for worldwide assignments
    </p>
  
    <a class="font-mono-space border px-4 py-2
       rounded-lg text-sm uppercase mt-8
       hover:bg-white hover:text-gray-800
       inline-block opacity-0" id="viewWorkBtn" style="transform:translateY(30px)"
       href="#">View Work</a>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the minimal CSS, as it's mostly using Tailwind CSS:

```
/* Reset */
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

The following three pictures show going from (1) portrait, to (2) landscape, and back to (3) portrait.

[image]

[image]

[image]

So, it seems to be a basic CSS issue, caused by the large canvas moving around and affecting other CSS div elements.

I tried all sorts of ideas by changing colors on DIV elements, but this is the joy of CSS. Even using Tailwind templates or other ideas won't deal with the fundamental CSS positioning. Any ideas how to troubleshoot this, or how what the basic strategy is to fix it?  The fact that it works perfectly when simply commenting out the canvas, suggests it's pretty much a good working model.

Comment: The overly big canvas element is likely to blame, causing the browser to automatically zoom out, so that this element "fits" into the given space. But we don't know anything yet about what you are doing with this canvas, what styles you have applied, etc. Specifying a `max-width: 100%` for it might work in fixing the issue, but depending on what your animation code is actually doing, you might end up with a "squished" animation, when the actual canvas size and its dimensions don't match any more.

Comment: You are the man!  I tried max-width on body, as well as 'width=100%', but that didn't work. Yes...you are right.  "style="max-width: 100%;" on canvas element works!  All the javascript code does is stuff like - camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight and
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight).  Thanks!!